# Add a permanent association to Links?

Tags: linux, browser, content-type-association

I'm using [Links](http://links.sourceforge.net/) on a Ubuntu server, and to view images I'm using [Asciiview](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aview/), which works well, but the association is not retained whenever I close links.  How can I retain this association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the association and hit `Escape-s-s` to save the settings.